# How to take fileuploader value in button click function .button in update panel file uploader in outside of update panel

Tags: c#

I have put asp button in update panel and  asp file uploader in outside of update panel in server side button click function i am geting file uploader empty.give me any idea..my code is below

```
     <asp:FileUpload  runat="server" ID="DecFormUpload"/>

     <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdateDecForm" UpdateMode="Conditional">   
               <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="DecFormUploadClick" OnClick="DecFormUploadClick_Click" OnClientClick="return DecFormUploadClick_Save();" runat="server" Text="Upload" />
         </ContentTemplate>      
                     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

c# code

```
  protected void DecFormUploadClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(DecFormUpload.HasFile)//my problem is getting  false here
    {
       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to that FileUpload needs a full postback, add the following just after your :

```
<Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="DecFormUploadClick" />
        </Triggers>
```

Hope it helps